# Using awk to manipulate data from two sources

Tags: bash, awk

As part of CI\CD process in my team, I want to generate dynamic commands script from a file containing paths to some resources.

The file paths.txt contains the paths, separated by new lines. For every line in this file, a command should be generated, unless it starts with "JarPath/..."

example:

```
JarPath/DontTouchMe.jar
path/to/some/resource/View/PutMeInScript.msgflow
path/to/some/resource/Control/MeAlso.map
```

The file mapping.txt contains a key-values pairs. the key is a phrase to be matched with a path from paths.txt, and it's value is required for the generated command.

example:

```
View viewEG.bar
Control controlEG.bar
```

Lines in paths.txt  are not sorted, and some paths can match a single value in mapping.txt.
Only the first match in the mapping.txt file that matches the first possible parse in the path should be considered. I don't care if later line in mapping also matches, nor if later directory in the path matches other line.
The to-be-matched parse at the path is not at fixed location (e.g after the 4th "/")

Final result in the script file should be:

```
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b viewEG.bar -o /path/to/some/resource/View/PutMeInScript.msgflow
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b controlEG.bar -o /path/to/some/resource/Control/MeAlso.map
```

Since the command line takes data from two sources (paths.txt and a value pair from mapping.txt) I couldn't wrap it into single awk command, nor pipeline it to single bash line. I wrote:

```
pathVar="paths.txt"
touch deltaFile.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
  awk -v var=$line" 'var ~ $1 && var !~ /^JarPath/ {print $2, " ", var ;exit}' mapping.txt >>  deltaFile.txt
done < "$pathVar"
IFS=$'\n'
awk '{print "mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b", $1, "-o", $2 }' deltaFile.txt > script.sh
```

Well, it works, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that there is never a need to `touch` a file before writing to it, you can just write to it directly. So no need for `touch datafile.txt`, the ` >>  deltaFile.txt` will create it if it doesn't exist. Of course, if it _does_ exist, then the new data will be appended to it, so instead of `touch datafile`, you might want to use `rm datafile`.

Comment: What correlates `View viewEG.bar` to `path/to/some/resource/View/PutMeInScript.msgflow`? Just file order? I see the matching directory, but I assume those will be repeated...?

Comment: @PaulHodges note the var ~ $1 in the first awk command

Comment: Yes, `View` matching `.../View/...`, but are those unique? And is it always the 5th element in the path?

Comment: @PaulHodges It's not unique, first match counts, see ...;exit on first awk. It's not always the 5th element in the path.

Comment: I think an associative array might save you some work. Still making sure I understand the data... How large are these files?

Comment: @PaulHodges It's CI/CD... I can't guarantee the size of paths.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comment below that `Only the first match in the mapping.txt file that matches the first possible parse in the path should be considered. The key dir can appear anywhere` this is what you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    keys[++numKeys] = $1
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
!/^JarPath/ {
    numDirs = split($0,dirs,"/")
    val = ""
    for (dirNr=1; (dirNr<=numDirs) && (val==""); dirNr++) {
        dir = dirs[dirNr]
        for (keyNr=1; (keyNr<=numKeys) && (val==""); keyNr++) {
            key = keys[keyNr]
            if (dir == key) {
                val = map[dir]
            }
        }
    }
    printf "mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b \047%s\047 -o \047%s\047\n", val, $0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk mapping.txt paths.txt
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b 'viewEG.bar' -o 'path/to/some/resource/View/PutMeInScript.msgflow'
mqsicreatebar -data ./ -b 'controlEG.bar' -o 'path/to/some/resource/Control/MeAlso.map'
```

Comment: About the matching, both assumptions are are correct. Only the first match in the mapping.txt file that matches the first possible parse in the path should be considered. The key dir can appear anywhere. Thank your for your time

Comment: What forces map[] to preserve the original file lines order?

Comment: The answers before the update don't process your mapping file in order, that's what the update was for. `map[]` doesn't store any order as it's just a hash lookup mapping a key to a value, `keys[++numKeys] = $1` does. For efficiency there has to be 2 arrays - one to store the order of the keys and the other to map the keys to their values.

Comment: I updated my answer to just show the script you actually need given what you said in your comments.